# Webpack : errors with manifest.json

Tags: reactjs, webpack, manifest

I've a **manifest.json** file, and I suppose it's not taken into account on my web application. Indeed, when I put my app on my homescreen, I don't have the right picture (set inside the manifest.json file), and when I open it, the behavior is like a shortcut, not really like a **PWA** *(like the name is not the name that I've put into my manifest.json, 'short_name' entry)*

On the **Network panel**, I've **HTTP CODE 200** :

[image]

BUT, the preview panel display **"You need to enable JavaScript to run this app."**

**Note** that the Response panel on my browser show me the index.html content, not the manifest.json content :
[image]

**I've tried to :**

- Moove the manifest.json file into /dist directory (my manifest.json file is in my public directory).
- Moove the images inside the manifest.json in other directories.

Same with my favicon, the application doesn't find it, but it seems that it's succesfully reach it (200).

**Note** that in development (localhost), my favicon is displayed. And I've no trouble with images that are 'require' inside my app.

My manifest.json (inside public directory) :

```
{
  "short_name": "Short name",
  "name": "Name",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": ".",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

Comment: Have you added a link tag in your index.html in the public folder? Like 

`<link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />`

Comment: The link to my manifest.json into my index.html is <link rel="manifest" href="./public/manifest.json" />,

Comment: When you go to the Applications tab, and then Manisfest on the left hand side of it, what does it show?

Comment: The manifest.json file is not detected (blank file). I'm trying to put manifest.json into dist folder (changing the manifest path to simply 'manifes.json'), with the images, and it seems that's working. Is this a good way to do ?

Comment: Yeah, placing it in the root of your public/dist isn't an issue. I want to know if its being picked up by your index.html

Comment: Yay, great work!

Comment: It's works by editing path of manifest.json, and put images into dist/ folder (at least, I've data into Application > manifest.json folder and no error), thank you!